# How do you update a file in SVN using Eclipse gui from your local pc

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

[image]

I always end up deleting and replacing instead of update.

How do you update a file in SVN using eclipse gui from your local pc
I don't want to check in the whole parent folder. Just the file - I want to update it

I don't have so many options in my right click perspective .

Attached is my screen-shot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you're using Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1) with Java Project...

You can do a mouse right-click on the file to access the item "Team" on the context menu:
[image: Screenshot in Java Perspective])
and then you have two options:

- Synchronize the file with SVN and be redirected to the "Team Synchronizing" Perspective, to update the file doing a mouse right-click and clicking on the "Update" menu item
  [image: Screenshot in Team Sunchronizing Perspective]
- or, click directly on the "update to HEAD" menu item (or "Update to version") to make the update without changing the Eclipse perspective.

Comment: I added an update to my Q wrt your reply. TY again for your reply

Comment: Well, it seems that we're talking about different subjects.
Can you add information about the Eclipse Version and project type (PHP, Python, Java...) that you're using?

Comment: Eclipse SDK

Version: 3.5.1
Build id: M20090917-0800  We  have several folders . doc - has all documentation . Bin has all shell scripts etc. Java_src has .java lib  has . jar etc. I am currently trying to update my shells in the bin directory

Comment: Do you have any SVN plugin configured? Like Subclipse or Subversive? And do you installed any connector (SVNKit or JavaHL)?

By the way, these menus that I showed in the screenshots are provided by the Subclipse plugin

Comment: Oh... It seems that you have the Subversive plugin installed. I'll check if there is any way to update a single file with this plugin.

Comment: Yes I installed subversion otherwise I cant open SVN using eclipse

Comment: So, could you check the version of the SVN plugin (under the menu Help/About Eclipse)?
Also, we need to know if your project is connected to a SVN repository, to help you further. Do a mouse right click on the project and inside the Properties dialog, look for Resource URL on the "SVN Info" item, or "Subversion" item (if you're using this last plugin).

Comment: svn://scm.it.billmelater.com:14543 I have attached the plugin screen shot ty

Comment: Ok- so lets think of easier solutions - if I install subeclipse- can it handle SVN and with SubE - would I see that team menu - then I'd do just that

Comment: Probably not. That's the problem! With the default installation, the menu item "Team" is already provided. Just to double check it... Do you have the "Team" item in the mouse right-click menu?